# How to migrate from react-router v1 to v4 ? {this.props.children}

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Been trying to migrate from react-dom version 1 to v4.

Since older react-router versions used nested routes it is a little counter-intuitive in v4 since you can basically put `<Route />`s everywhere. And from official v4 docs it might seem unclear how to migrate this piece - {this.props.children} since it uses history component to use hash portion of the URL. 
I thought I had to use `<Router history={history}></Router>` to get it working in v4. However, `<HashRouter></HashRouter>` is the way to go with v4 in this case. 
Check it out below.

So, to give you a quick example here's what I had in v1:

v1.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router";
import Index from './components/Index';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

let documentReady = () => {
  const reactNode = document.getElementById('react');
  if(reactNode){
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path='/', component={Index} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
      , reactNode);
  }
};

$(documentReady)
```

And here's working example of

v4.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Index from './components/Index';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Index} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

let documentReady = () => {
  const reactNode = document.getElementById('react');
  if(reactNode){
    ReactDOM.render(
      <HashRouter>
        <Route component={App} />
      </HashRouter>
      , reactNode);
  }
};

$(documentReady)
```

Note that you have to import HashRouter instead of Router v4, whereas in v1 it was a History, a separate package to be installed along with react-router.

Hope that saves somebody time and

Here's a great resource from François Zaninotto => [React Router v4 Unofficial Migration Guide](https://codeburst.io/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a)

Comment: Hi this isn't a question but some advice and is unsuitable for posting here as this is for Q&A format only

Comment: Is this better @DominicTobias ? Or should I remove this post entirely?

Comment: Just a second.(I forgot a question mark)